# Authbind Permission Error when binding socket to port

Tags: permissions, port

I’m running a Jupyter Notebook server on my Mac, and I’m trying to use authbind to run the notebook server on port 443. I’ve created the file /etc/authbind/byport/443, changed the ownership to the account running the server, and changed the permissions to 777. I’ve checked that the server is configured to run on port 443. However, when I run `authbind jupyter notebook` here are the last few lines of error output:
`File "/Users/asianzhang/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 197, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`
Also, I checked that nc could bind to port 443 without a problem.
Could you tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the port 443, you should create the file `/etc/authbind/byport/443` instead of `/etc/authbind/byport/80` and set ownership to the user running the server.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I created and modified the permissions for both 80 and 443 just in case. I also ran some tests, and nc could bind to the port, but jupyter notebook couldn’t, using the same account and directory. I updated the question.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add the flag --deep to the command